# How SaveChanges method works in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I'm working on a desktop application using EntityFramework and PostgreSQL, and since ef doesn't handle db permissions, I would like to know if `SaveChanges()` will update the entire row or just modified columns? (problem of foreign keys deleting after row update)

Comment: Save Changes on what class?

Comment: This depends on your implementation and the EF provider you are using. EF allows you to set single columns to modified, and some providers will actually only set these columns then in an update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SaveChanges() method goes to save all changes made to the database context which have not been pushed to the database yet, in other words, saves on the database all changes made to the context since the last call to SaveChanges() happened.

The method goes and saves the data as currently available in the context, which means it will update the entire row, not just the column you changed, if a property of your object model is set to NULL, the framework will try to save NULL in that mapping column in the database.

Answer (score -1):

The EntityFramework dbContext savechanges will try and populate the change state of your orm mapped items

Have a [look at this](https://entityframework.net/save-changes) for a EF sample.

Depending your [driver](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) the implementation may differ.